# IdentityServer4 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type when trying to refresh token

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity, refresh-token, identitymodel

I have identityserver4 v2.4 setup to user ASP.Net Identity and Entity Framework as an operational store. When I call `tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(oldRefreshToken);` as follows, I always get an `invalid_grant` error in the `tokenResult`

```
TokenClient tokenClient = new TokenClient(tokenEndpoint, clientId, clientSecret);
string oldRefreshToken = await context.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);
TokenResponse tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(oldRefreshToken);
```

The IDS4 logs show an ArgumentException in the logs (Note that there are a lot of similar issues with the Parameter name being `value` instead of `Parameter name: type` as is in my case. I do not think they are related since the fixes recommended for those did not work for me). The exceptions seems to get raised in the IDS4 ClaimsConverter. I did check my MySQL database for any null values fields in the asp.net user and claims tables and confirmed there are none:

```
[14:17:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start token request validation

[14:17:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start validation of refresh token request

[14:17:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore
pY3Q91B7RFXV2ilzuJtI+ggqkOg9xiRx4HcGZMfJf+0= found in database: True

[14:17:12 Error] IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultRefreshTokenStore
Failed to deserialize JSON from grant store.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType, String issuer, String originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, String propertyKey, String propertyValue)
   at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.Serialization.ClaimConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\Storage\src\Stores\Serialization\ClaimConverter.cs:line 24
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultGrantStore`1.GetItemAsync(String key) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\src\Stores\Default\DefaultGrantStore.cs:line 92

[14:17:12 Warning] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator
Invalid refresh token

[14:17:12 Warning] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Refresh token validation failed. aborting.
```

My Client config in IDS4 is as follows

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "AspNetClient",
    ClientName = "ASP.Net Client",

    RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:5003/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
    RequireClientSecret = true,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("AspNetClientSecret".Sha256())
    },                    

    RequireConsent = false,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "AccessTokenAuthorizedApi"
    },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,                    
    AccessTokenLifetime = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalSeconds,
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = (int) TimeSpan.FromDays(30).TotalSeconds,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2019-05-15:**

So I did a little more digging and retrieved the actual record in the PersistedGrants table using the key found in the log which is `pY3Q91B7RFXV2ilzuJtI+ggqkOg9xiRx4HcGZMfJf+0=`. I can see 4 empty claims in the JSON text from the `Data` field which must be causing the issue. But why does IDS4 add empty claims like this?

```
{
   "CreationTime":"2019-05-15T08:47:03Z",
   "Lifetime":2592000,
   "AccessToken":{
      "Audiences":[
         "http://localhost:5000/resources",
         "AccessTokenAuthorizedApi"
      ],
      "Issuer":"http://localhost:5000",
      "CreationTime":"2019-05-15T08:47:03Z",
      "Lifetime":10,
      "Type":"access_token",
      "ClientId":"AspNetClient",
      "AccessTokenType":0,
      "Claims":[
         {
            "Type":"client_id",
            "Value":"AspNetClient",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"scope",
            "Value":"openid",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"scope",
            "Value":"profile",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"scope",
            "Value":"email",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"scope",
            "Value":"AccessTokenAuthorizedApi",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"scope",
            "Value":"offline_access",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"sub",
            "Value":"0170490c-24c9-4be4-ae2a-5d4b1c55346e",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"auth_time",
            "Value":"1557910023",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
         },
         {
            "Type":"idp",
            "Value":"local",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"amr",
            "Value":"pwd",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp",
            "Value":"IF6RRMICBOOITA56FEJLPTFBXCIUKW3Z",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"role",
            "Value":"Driver",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"role",
            "Value":"Helper",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"preferred_username",
            "Value":"hybrid1",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {
            "Type":"name",
            "Value":"hybrid1",
            "ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
         },
         {

         },
         {

         },
         {

         },
         {

         }
      ],
      "Version":4
   },
   "Version":4
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like IDS4 is not serializing derived claims objects as I expected it to. I was using a custom TenantClaim class which inherits Claim and added 4 such objects in my custom IProfileService implementation in the IdentityServer project like so:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    // Other Code

    var tenantRoleClaim = new TenantRoleClaim(tenantRole.TenantId, tenantRole.Role);
    claims.Add(tenantRoleClaim);

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
}
```

Once I changed it to use plain old Claim type objects, the code worked.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    // Other Code

    var tenantRoleClaim = new TenantRoleClaim(tenantRole.TenantId, tenantRole.Role);
    claims.Add(new Claim(tenantRoleClaim.Type, tenantRoleClaim.Value));

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
}
```